# Ao iniciar uma aplicação, executar tarefa do Windows

Tags: windows, log-de-eventos-windows

Estou procurando uma maneira de executar uma tarefa do windows sempre que um aplicativo for iniciado. Preciso rodar um VBS ou um BAT sempre que um aplicativo for iniciado (ele é iniciado por um segundo app após o usuário informar seu login e senha no mesmo)...

Alguém sabe se isso é possível? Consigo criar uma trigger, ou algo parecido? um serviço que fique lendo o log do windows e se "X" aplicativo for iniciado ele faz alguma coisa?

Comment: Você não sabe onde colocar isto? Ou como chamar/executar o aplicativo? Você sabe qual é o *script* que precisa ser chamado? Você criou essa aplicação que precisa chamar o *script*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos supor que você queira executar o `y.exe` sempre que o `x.exe` for executado. O que você pode fazer é:

1. Renomear o `x.exe` para `z.exe`.
2. Criar um novo programa `x.exe` que execute ambos, o `z.exe` e o `y.exe`, repassando ao `z.exe` os mesmos parâmetros de linha de comando recebidos (ou se for interessante, alguns parâmetros diferentes).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um serviço que monitore a lista de processos ativos e detecte a presença do aplicativo em questão.

Se você for usar .NET, a lista de processos pode ser acessada com `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()`.